# Real-time chat: Is it better to use Node.js as a middle-man or not?

Tags: php, node.js, chat, real-time

I was wondering whether it is good to use Node.js as a middle-man or not - meaning:

> Sending message data to Node.js server, that sending it to website's
>   API and then sending back notifications to chat participants. *(This
>   is what I am currently using)*

**or**

> Sending data via AJAX to PHP to process and simultaneously send data
>   to Node.js server to only notify chat participants.

I would like to know whether is my approach correct or not. What are the best practices to solve real-time chatting with PHP web-app and Node.js?

*Also*, what is the best way to solve sessions between PHP and Node.js? Redis? - Why?

Thanks for your time,
TheKronnY

Comment: Why is PHP involved at all in the chat bit?

Comment: Whole web is built in PHP, what do you mean why it is involved? Chat is not like standalone feature.

Comment: I mean that it _should_ be standalone, at least as far as the server side. Normally the web page would connect to the Node server via a WebSocket or the like, and the Node server would receive messages and broadcast them to other people in a given chat. The web server seems like it would just be getting in the way in this scenario, if it has any part after serving the page.

Comment: So, you are saying that after serving the webpage, everything should be handled by Node.js server?

Comment: Everything regarding the chat, i'd think so.

Comment: Okay! Any tips about the user authentication when connecting to Node.js server?

Comment: Just a thought: If PHP and Node can share sessions, a bunch of the authentication worries fade away -- you could use the session ID if you wanted.